# make many loops into single loop (NOT nested for loop)

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, filter, zip

suppose I have many independent for loop. how do I write in one line where I do a loop over both list_A and list_B?

I'm aware of the **zip()** function but it only works as intended if len(list_A) = len(list_B).
my list_A and list_B have different length. and i need to guarantee x is performed on list_A and list_B simultaneously. any ideas on how I can achieve this in a single line?

```
for i in list_A:
     try:
        do x on list_A
     except Error: 
        pass

for i in list_B:
     try:
        do x on list_B
     except Error:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a counter for parsing through the list.
2. Compare the while condition with Max of the lengths of the lists
3. Run the loop and perform the process. (Be mindful to add a condition to check if counter is greater than the list's length)

Here's example:

```
 i = 0
 while (i < max(len(list_A), len(list_B))):
    if(i < len(list_A)):
        x(list_A[i])
    if(i < len(list_B)):
        x(list_B[i])
    i = i +1
```